# Add hidden input types based on radio button selected

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to conditionally add hidden input fields into a form?

eg I have a php form that is adding values to a table and if the appleID = 1 or 2 then I want 1 added to the fruits column of my table and if appleID =3 I want 1 added to the sweets column of my table.  I thought I might be able to do something like the below but it is adding all hidden values no matter what I select.  Or should I approach this a different way?

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="appleID" />
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="fruits" />
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="sweets" />

<input type="radio" value="2" name="appleID" />
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="fruits" />
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="sweets" />

<input type="radio" value="3" name="appleID" />
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="fruits" />
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="sweets" />
```

---

Thanks I haven't done much with php so I will need to explore that option further.  Thanks for the feedback.
I was also looking at something like the below.  But PHP sounds likes the better option.
[change field value when select radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322525/change-field-value-when-select-radio-buttons)

Comment: Why not handle this when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use all values in the radio buttons (1,1,0 - 2,1,0 - 3,0,1) and split them after receiving them in your PHP script or add/delete the hidden fields via JavaScript.

Split Example:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" value="1,1,0" name="appleID" />
<input type="radio" value="2,1,0" name="appleID" />
<input type="radio" value="3,0,1" name="appleID" />
```

PHP:

```
if (!empty($_POST['appleID']))
{
    list($appleID, $fruits, $sweets) = explode(",", $_POST['appleID']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I haven't done much with php so I will need to explore that option further.  Thanks for the feedback.
I was also looking at something like the below.  But PHP sounds likes the better option.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322525/change-field-value-when-select-radio-buttons

Answer (score 0):

It is better to put that logic into the PHP script instead of using Javascript - because you have to do the validation anyway.